# "Image.fromarray" causes "OverflowError: size does not fit in an int" error in large scale images

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I am using this [code](https://github.com/deroneriksson/python-wsi-preprocessing/tree/master/deephistopath/wsi) for processing Whole Slide Images (.svs format). This code running well when [NUM_TOP_TILES = 50](https://github.com/deroneriksson/python-wsi-preprocessing/blob/master/deephistopath/wsi/tiles.py#L40) to `NUM_TOP_TILES = 12000`. As Whole Slide Images are very large in size, in that case if I increase `NUM_TOP_TILES>12000`, I'm getting error

> OverflowError: size does not fit in an int error.

This is very common issue with `Pillow` when large images were used. There are many solutions are available in the `github` and `StackOverFlow` but I'm not able to solve my issue. As per my analysis, `Image.fromarray()` of `Pillow` in the below function causing this issue. It will be a great help if anyone suggest any solution to solve this issue. I have given related `function` and `error traceback` for your reference.

**Function:**

```
def np_to_pil(np_img):
  """
  Convert a NumPy array to a PIL Image.
  Args:
    np_img: The image represented as a NumPy array.
  Returns:
     The NumPy array converted to a PIL Image.
  """
  if np_img.dtype == "bool":
    np_img = np_img.astype("uint8") * 255
  elif np_img.dtype == "float64":
    np_img = (np_img * 255).astype("uint8")
return Image.fromarray(np_img)
```

**Error Traceback**

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "WsiToImagePatch.py", line 35, in np_to_pil
    return Image.fromarray(np_img)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2536, in fromarray
    return frombuffer(mode, size, obj, "raw", rawmode, 0, 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2479, in frombuffer
    return frombytes(mode, size, data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2412, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 812, in frombytes
    s = d.decode(data)
OverflowError: size does not fit in an int
```

Comment: So, say your `float64` value is 76,321.9 and you multiply it by 255 and put the result in an `np.uint8` which can handle a range from 0..255, what value are you expecting?

Comment: See when Shape: (221021, 540, 3), then I'm facing error. `Type: uint8   Shape: (1977, 2739, 3)
Type: uint8   Shape: (2284, 2744, 3)
Type: uint8   Shape: (221021, 540, 3)`